# How to select fields from SetColumn[String] in Phantom

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, phantom-dsl, phantom-types

I have a Cassandra table `Department` with columns `name_list extends SetColumn[String] with PartitionKey` and `id extends StringColumn with PartitionKey`.

I want to fetch **id** where the requested ***name*** is present in **name_list**.

I tried using this code below but not getting any results

```
abstract class Departments extends Table[Departments, Department] with RootConnector {

  object id extends StringColumn with PartitionKey

  object dep_type extends StringColumn

  object name_list extends SetColumn[String] with Index

      def getByName(name: String) = {
        select(_.id, _.name_list)
          .where(_.name_list.contains(name))
          .allowFiltering()
          .one()
      }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this!!

Comment: @flavian Can you check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we do not need to extend Index for it. It is working fine with this too:-

```
object name_list extends SetColumn[String]
```

Now, I am getting id and name_list by using the same method as above:-

```
def getByName(name: String) = {
    select(_.id, _.name_list)
      .where(_.name_list.contains(name))
      .allowFiltering()
      .one()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema has to be:

`object name_list extends SetColumn[String] with Index`

Without secondary indexing Cassandra does not support collection operations.

Comment: Thanks for helping @flavian but still I am not getting any response.

Comment: I have updated the question Please take a look Thanks

Comment: Does the query compile and work but you don't get any results from Cassandra?

Comment: Yes @flavian I run the query but I don't get any results from Cassandra

Comment: That's your data being wrong for whatever reason, it's not to do with phantom. Try to run the same thing from cqlsh, see if you get results. If it is phantom let me know.

Comment: When I am using another way to make it run it is working fine -                                 `
    `select.fetch().map(_.find(_.name_list.contains(query)).map(entity => (entity.uri, entity.question_type)))`